# HDF5 OSX pre-built

Tags: macos, hdf5, alembic

Does anyone have or know of a pre-built HDF5 on OSX somewhere?

The one I compiled myself gives me some mismatch errors and does not work in some cases. I mainly need it to use it with Alembic.

Comment: How about with a package manager? [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Are three that pop into my mind the quickest.

Comment: The homebrew I tried didn't work for me either, unfortunately. I think it was an old version of it.

Comment: @Yasin Did you run `brew update` before `brew install hdf5`?

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install homebrew/science/hdf5
```

seems to work